# Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required

Tags: mvc, php7

Tengo un problema al intentar crear un ejercicio muy simple de mvc con las rutas, ya he probado a ponerlas de varias formas distintas y en 2 ides distintas, dreamweaver y phpstorm. Uso el paquete wammp. Version de php 7.4.2

He provado a poner los directorios en el require_once de varias formas:

-`require_once("C:\wamp\www\mvcphpstorm\ vista\productos-view.php");`

-`require_once("vista/productos-view.php");`

-`require_once("/vista/productos-view.php");`

-`require_once("../vista/productos-view.php");`

Llevo 3 días indagando e indagando y nada me ha funcionado.

---

Esquema del directorio

```
-mvcphpstorm
   --modelo
    ---conexion-modelo.php
     ---productos-modelo.php
   --vista
     ---productos-view.php
   --controlador
     ---productos-controlador.php
   index.php
```

---

Os indico lo que tengo en cada archivo

En conexion-modelo.php

```php
<?


//CLASE

class Conectar{



    //Metodo conexion

    public function conexion(){


        try{


            $conexion=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=mvc;','root','');

            $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); //Definimos los atributos del metodo con setAttribute

            $conexion->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");//Utilizamos el metodo exec para definir la cadena de caracteres que queremos




        }catch (Exception $error){


            die ("Error " . $error->getLine() . $error->getMessage());


        }


        //Hacemos que el metodo nos devuelva la conexion si esta ha sido exitosa

        return $conexion;

    }

    //FIN DEL METODO







}
//FIN DE LA CLASE





?>
```

En productos-modelo.php

```php
<?php


//CLASE-
class Productos_modelo{



    private $db;

    private $productos;

    //CONSTRUCTOR--

    public function __construct(){


        require_once("C:\wamp\www\mvcphpstorm\modelo\conexion-modelo.php");

        $this->db=Conectar::conexion(); //convertimos db en la conexion llamando al metodo conexion

        $this->productos=array();//convierto $productos en un array




    }

    //FIN DEL CONSTRUCTOR--

    //METODO---

    public function get_productos(){


        $consulta=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM PRODUCTOS");


        while($filas=$consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

            $this->productos[]=$filas;


        }

        return $this->productos;


    }//FIN DEL METODO---




}//FIN DE LA CLASE-


?>
```

En productos-view.php

```php
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Documento sin título</title>
    <style>

        td{

            border: 2px #0066FF;


        }


    </style>


</head>

<body>

<table>

    <?php

    foreach($arrayproductos as $registro){

        echo "<tr><td>" . $registro["Id"] . "</td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td>" . $registro["Nombre"] . "</td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td>" . $registro["Descripcion"] . "</td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td>" . $registro["Precio"] . "</td></tr>";

    }

    ?>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

En productos-controlador.php

```php
<?php

require_once("C:\wamp\www\mvcphpstorm\modelo\productos-modelo.php");

require_once("C:\wamp\www\mvcphpstorm\ vista\productos-view.php");



$producto= new Productos_modelo(); //Instanciamos la clase y a la vez se ejecuta el constructor

$arrayproductos=$producto->get_productos(); //creo un array y le digo que es igual a lo que le pase el metodo get_productos()



?>
```

En mi index.php

```php
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Documento sin título</title>

    <style>


        h1{

            text-align:center;

        }




    </style>


</head>

<body>
<h1>Modelo vista controlador</h1><br>


<?php

require_once("C:\wamp\www\mvcphpstorm\controlador\productos-controlador.php");





?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Como te indica el error, es un problema de rutas.. yo te sugeriria que si estas llamando **C:\wamp\www\mvcphpstorm\controlador\productos-controlador.php**
esa ruta, pues podrias colocarla de la siguiente manera **productos-controlador.php** en caso de que el archivo se encuentre en la misma carpeta, sino empieza a validar, recuerda que esto ./ indica salir de la carpeta actual, devolverse mas ../ y asi sucesivamente, o puedes poner una foto del directorio , seria mas facil identificar

Answer (score 0):

Fijate que tenes un espacio antes de "vista" en:
`require_once("C:\wamp\www\mvcphpstorm\ vista\productos-view.php");`

Ademas de eso, no hay razon para que no funcione a simple vista.
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con rutas relativas.

Ejemplo:

```
require_once("./modelo/productos-modelo.php");

require_once("./../modelo/productos-modelo.php");
```

Answer (score -1):

No se si tenga que ver pero en el archivo conexion-modelo.php no abriste correctamente la etiqueta de PHP, esta con esto "<?" y debería estar "<?php".